# Developing C# Winforms software using SQL Server 2012 in Visual Studio 2012 and running it on other system without installing SQL Server 2012

Tags: c#-4.0, visual-studio-2012, .net-4.5, sql-server-2012-express

I wanted to develop a C# application oriented software using SQL Server 2012 in Visual Studio 2012. But if I install the software on another computer with out installing SQL Server 2012 database, how will this software work and access the data?

Is there any method and function or namespace that can provide the default storage space to store the data after the software is installed on a system?

Answer (score 2):

If you develop an application that use Sql Server 2012 as storage for your data then you need to install it in a way or another. There are numerous versions of Sql Server, like Sql Server Express and LocalDB. In every case you need the bits that supports your coding calls.

This [magazine article](http://sqlmag.com/sql-server-2012/sql-server-2012-express-editions) summarizes relevant infos on the various version of Sql Server

I suppose that the right product for you is [Sql Server LocalDB](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlexpress/archive/2011/07/12/introducing-localdb-a-better-sql-express.aspx). A version of Sql Server that could be distributed easily with your application setup and doesn't require a complex installation procedure.

However, if you don't foresee the need to escalate you application to a full Client-Server model and you need only a local storage for a single user, you could choose a single file database like [Sql Server Compact Edition](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=17876) or [SQLite](http://system.data.sqlite.org/index.html/doc/trunk/www/index.wiki) or even MS Access.